# Remove post loop on homepage of Twenty Fourteen Wordpress and keep pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to keep just the featured content so only the gallery is shown on homepage so I am trying to disable the post loop which I can do easily but I am having trouble keeping the pagination when removing it.

Here is the code

```
<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

I would also try doing it in CSS

```
.home .post-37401 {
display: none;
}
```

This is to remove a specific post but I want to try removing all posts without messing with the featured gallery

Comment: Do you want to just  keep pagination ? please paste here your website link

Comment: This worked anyone who needs this....

Answer (score 0):

This worked anyone who needs this...

```
<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
$xpaged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
global $paged;

if ( $paged  > 1 ) {                    
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
}
                endwhile;
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: everyone who didn't help thanks for nothing, this is a community you should try and help when you can.